# Execute Jquery method from Razor Form

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, razor

When I clicked on the submit button, it takes the form fields which are Email, Password and FName and executes the controller event instead of going through the jQuery method given below.

In the jQuery method I have edited the EMAIL address to be `sdsdsd@sdd.dd`, However, in the controller I see the value that I entered in the Form Field. So, I think that my jQuery method hasn't been fired.

```
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
@Html.AntiForgeryToken()

@Html.ValidationSummary()
<div class="form-group">
    @Html.LabelFor(m => m.EMAIL, new { @class = "col-md-2 control-label" })
    <div class="col-md-10">
        @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.EMAIL, new { id = "Email", @class = "form-control" })
    </div>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    @Html.LabelFor(m => m.PASSWORD, new { @class = "col-md-2 control-label" })
    <div class="col-md-10">
        @Html.PasswordFor(m => m.PASSWORD, new { id = "pwd", @class = "form-control" })
    </div>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    @Html.LabelFor(m => m.ConfirmPassword, new { @class = "col-md-2 control-label" })
    <div class="col-md-10">
        @Html.PasswordFor(m => m.ConfirmPassword, new { @class = "form-control" })
    </div>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Fname, new { @class = "col-md-2 control-label" })
    <div class="col-md-10">
        @Html.PasswordFor(m => m.Fname, new { @class = "form-control" })
    </div>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
        <input type="submit" class="btn btn-default" value="Register" id="submitbuttonid"  />
    </div>
</div>

}
```

**JQUERY**

```
$(function () {
            $('submitbuttonid').click(function () {
                if ($(this).valid()) {
                    $.ajax({
                        url: '/Action/Register',
                        type: this.method,
                        data: {EMAIL : "sdsdsd@sdd.dd"},
                        success: function (result) {
                            $('#result').html(result);
                        }
                    });
                }
                return false;
            });
        });
```

**CONTROLLER**

```
    [AllowAnonymous]
    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult Register(RegisterViewModel acc)
    {
        return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
    }
```

**UPDATE**

```
@using (Html.BeginForm(null,null,FormMethod.Post, new { id = "yourFormId" }))
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    <strong>Hi </strong>
    @Html.Label("Text Content", new { id = "lastnamelbl" })
    @Html.Label("Text Content", new { id = "firstnamelbl" })
    <hr />
    @Html.ValidationSummary()
    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(m => m.EMAIL, new { @class = "col-md-2 control-label" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.EMAIL, new { id = "Email", @class = "form-control" })
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(m => m.PASSWORD, new { @class = "col-md-2 control-label" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.PasswordFor(m => m.PASSWORD, new { id = "pwd", @class = "form-control" })
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(m => m.ConfirmPassword, new { @class = "col-md-2 control-label" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.PasswordFor(m => m.ConfirmPassword, new { @class = "form-control" })
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Fname, new { @class = "col-md-2 control-label" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.PasswordFor(m => m.Fname, new { @class = "form-control" })
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
            <input type="submit" class="btn btn-default" value="Register" id="submitbuttonid"  />
        </div>
    </div>

}
```

**JS**

```
 <script>


    $(function () {
        $('#yourFormId').on('submit', function (e) { //make it form submit event
            e.preventDefault(); // stop the form submission.
            if ($(this).valid()) {  // if form is valid, proceed with your ajax logic.
                // your current Code
                alert("jhjh");
                $.ajax({
                    url: '/Account/Register',
                    type: 'POST',
                    data: { EMAIL: "sdsdsd@sdd.dd" },
                    success: function (result) {
                        $('#result').html(result);
                    }
                });
            }
            return false;
        });
    });
```

**UPDATE**

```
<form action="/Account/Register/yourFormId" method="post"><input name="__RequestVerificationToken" type="hidden" value="poLluIrZEBZBe0Fr5QWfr5LoI4yrKn6Vc77gPYIE09RZc2qYvFxP3tNQ0UavJMc862RZ5Bd2vcEqKfmji39ktEnslbT38tKalIBeRD1la_U1" />
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your POST method is decorated with `[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]` but your not passing the token so an exception is thrown on the server. Either remove the attribute, or pass it in the request, for example

```
$('form').submit(function() {
    if (!$(this).valid()) {
        return;
    }
    var token = $('[name=__RequestVerificationToken]').val();
    $.ajax({
        url: '@Url.Action("Register", "Account")', // don't hard code
        type: 'POST',
        data: { EMAIL: "sdsdsd@sdd.dd", __RequestVerificationToken: token},
        success: function (result) {
            $('#result').html(result);
        }
    });
    return false; / you do not need .preventDefault() when this is included
});
```

However, this means your not passing any of the other properties of your model so unclear what your trying to achieve with this. To serialize all the controls in the form, including the token, you can use

```
$('form').submit(function() {
    var formData = $(this).serialize(); // can always use formdata.EMAIL = newValue; to update it
    ....
    $.ajax({
        ....
        data: formData,
```

Comment: In DATA, I want to pass fields like EMAIL and etc. Can I use your first approach if so ?

Comment: Yes, if you add every property manually, but why? The `.serialize()` method correctly serializes all the form controls.

Comment: There are some values I will have to pass without asking the user to type in the form. One more question. So is the code in my VIEW correct ? Do I have to alter it ?

Comment: Your `@Html.Label("Text Content", new { id = "lastnamelbl" })` makes no sense. And you should be adding `@Html.ValidationMessageFor()` for each property, and all your `new { id = "..." }` are pointless, but other that nthat its OK.

Comment: Not sure what your mean by _There are some values I will have to pass without asking the user to type in the form_? - that does not really make sense in a registration form. What values are you referring to?

Answer (score 1):

**Problem:** Is with the way your current code is,

```
$('submitbuttonid').click(function () { // You have a missing # in selector, Also this is click event of button
 if ($(this).valid()) { // $(this).valid() is always undefined, hence you ajax is never executed.
  // your current Code
 } 
return false;
});
```

**Solution:** Change the event to fire on form **submit()** rather than the button click

```
$('#yourFormId').on('submit',function (e) { //make it form submit event
 e.preventDefault(); // stop the form submission.
 if ($(this).valid()) {  // if form is valid, proceed with your ajax logic.
  // your current Code
 } 
return false;
});
```

Comment: Still, when I submit it takes the FORM fields EMAIL address instead of JQuery's email address. How can I correct this ?

Comment: @Illep can you place an `alert()` inside the `if` block and see if it works?

Comment: It didn't get fired.

Comment: @Illep did you add a `id` to your form and use that `id` in the jquery selector.. Also In my above scripts I have omitted the `$(function () {..` wrapper for clarity.. you need to have that too..

Comment: Still it's the same. I am newbie to this.

Comment: @Illep no problem.. Can you update your question with your new code for your `form` and `scripts`..

Comment: I replaced my FORM tag with this `@using (Html.BeginForm(null,null,FormMethod.Post, new { id = "yourFormId" }))
`

Comment: @Illep your code looks fine.. I am not sure what else might be wrong.. Can you check your browser console window and see if there are any jquery errors?

Comment: I have updated my post. I have updated my post with the page source. Can you please have a look. The ID gets appended to the URL.

Comment: @Illep 2 options,, 1) try replacing `null,null` with `"", "",` 2) change the script selector from `$('#yourFormId')` to `$('#submitbuttonid').closest('form')`

Comment: @Illep any progress?

Comment: Thank you for your help. I think it was because as mentioned by  @stephen  I have missed `ValidateAntiForgeryToken`

Answer (score 0):

The prameter  EMAIL in ajax method is String type. So you have to declare the same name and same type in your C# method like this:

```
[AllowAnonymous]
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult Register(string  Email)
{
    return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
}
```

Comment: No, I want to accept a Model it self. Not a String parameter. Anyway, the JS method doesn't get executed.